# How can the abscissa of the intersection point of the trigonometric functions and the x-axis be expressed by the precise value of $\pi$?

Tags: plotting

https://writings.stephenwolfram.com/2023/06/llm-tech-and-a-lot-more-version-13-3-of-wolfram-language-and-mathematica/

```
Plot[{Highlighted[Sin[x], Placed["XAxisLabel", {Automatic, 0}]]}, {x, 
  0, 20}]
```

[image]

How can the abscissa of the intersection point of the Trigonometric functions and the x-axis be expressed by the precise value of pi?

The abscissa values above are approximately represented by decimals. How can pi be used to accurately represent them?

Comment: `xTicks = Transpose[{#, TraditionalForm /@ #}] &@
  Range[0, 6 π, π]` and `Plot[Sin[x]
 , {x, 0, 6 π}
 , Ticks -> {xTicks, Automatic}
 ]`

Comment: Tick specification must be a list or a function

Comment: Does this work: `Plot[{Highlighted[Sin[x], Placed["XAxisLabel",Map[List][Pi Range[0,6]]]]}, {x,   0, 20}]`?

Comment: @kglr The software keeps showing running without calculating the result

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This [`Highlighted`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Highlighted.html) functionality  is a version 13.3 update. The labels are numerical.

[`Callout`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Callout.html) can achieve goal, e.g.

```
sol = {x, 0} /. Solve[{Sin[x] == 0, 0 <= x < 20}, x];
p = Show[Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 22}], 
  ListPlot[
   Callout[#, #[[1]], {Above, Left}, Appearance -> "Balloon", 
      CalloutMarker -> "CirclePoint", Background -> LightBlue] & /@ 
    sol]]
```

[image]

I am sure the style can be refined as desired.